# how to replace special characters from mysql string

Tags: mysql

there is a table in mysql database and it has strings, datatype is text, and the data which is inserted is as below

HELLO+THIS+IS+OFFER!!%+HURRY!!%0ACall+US+NOW%

How do I remove % and + special characters from this string, it looks like encoded string.

Best Regards 
CJ

Comment: you wan't to remove it with an UPDATE query or a programation langage ?

Comment: anything would do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below mysql function removes special characters from a string:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS replacespecialchars; 
DELIMITER | 
CREATE FUNCTION replacespecialchars( str CHAR(255) ) RETURNS CHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(255) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 );
      IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END | 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi Prashant Thats in MySQL

Comment: Hello Prashant, I need solution for MySQL Database

Comment: Edited above answer, hope it will help!!

Comment: Hey Chetan, just vote up if it fulfills your requirement. Thanks!!